# How can out string values with Task<bool> function in C#

Tags: c#, task, out

How can out string values with Task function in C#
i need fix this code to return Task with out string values

```
public Task<bool> DelUserTemp(string UserID, int FingerIndex ,out string result)
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        if (true)
        {
            result = "done";
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            result = "error";
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You can't have ref/out parameters in asynchronous methods

Comment: How would you see it working if you could? Imagine you store the task of `DelUserTemp`, do something with `result` before it's assigned, and then `await` the task. Use a custom return object, or a `ValueTuple`.

Comment: how can i return multi value from Task<bool> function in C#

Comment: I.... I literally told you in my comment above.

Comment: Typical example why providing too many options confuses learners. `Task` `out` `bla bla`.

Comment: Use tuples instead of out parameters

Comment: Having a method that just `Task.Run`s some other code is usually a bad design - just provide a method that runs synchronously and let the *caller* decide whether to use it directly or to `Task.Run` it. (Exception: CPU heavy work that shouldn't run on the calling thread)

Answer (score 6):

An alternative to using ref/out would be to return [C# 7.0 tuples](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/) instead.

```
public Task<(bool Worked, string Result)> DelUserTemp(string UserID, int FingerIndex)
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        if (true)
        {
            return (true, "done");
        }
        else
        {
            return (false, "error");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another example is to create `class` and return it:

```
public class MyResult
{
    public bool Succeeded {get;}
    public string ErrorMessage {get;}

    public MyResult(bool succeeded, string errorMessage)
    {
        Succeeded = succeeded;
        ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
    }
}

public Task<MyResult> DelUserTemp(string UserID, int FingerIndex ,out string result)
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        if (true)
        {
            return new MyResult(true, "done");
        }
        else
        {
            return new MyResult(false, "error");
        }
    });
}
```